# How to number admonitions in Sphinx?

Tags: python-sphinx

I am writing a book using Sphinx Documentation and I have a special `admonition` that is used quite often. But for better communicating with the other authors, I would like to have an automatic number in each of these special admonitions.

Say I input this:

```
Section
=======

.. admonition:: Observation

   text

.. admonition:: Observation

   text
```

I would like to get something like this for the HTML build:

```
<h2>Section</h2>

<div class="admonition-observation admonition">
<p class="first admonition-title">Observation 1</p>
<p>text</p>

<div class="admonition-observation admonition">
<p class="first admonition-title">Observation 2</p>
<p>text</p>
```

Or anything that gives me automatic numbering in the HTML source (and analogously for the latex source).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to use an extension, like https://github.com/rhopfer/sphinx-numbered-blocks

Once installed, a `conf.py` for your approach might look like this:

```
...
numbered_blocks = [
    {'name': 'observation'},
]
...
```

Then, in your source, you'd write this:

```
.. observation::

   This is an observation
```

Resulting in HTML:

```
<div class="numbered-block observation" id="observation-0">
  <span class="title">
  <span class="label">Observation 1.1</span><p>This is an observation</p></span>
</div>
```

(your exact output may differ slightly)

See https://git.io/vHQzJ for more configuration examples and how to modify the labels.